# Can't get "kr" p-value computation in tab_model (sjPlot) to work

Tags: r, sjplot

I'm trying to summarize a `lmer` model with `sjPlot::tab_model`. It works until I try to get "kr" p-values to also obtain degrees of freedom. I have `pbkrtest` installed, and can use it separately, but it's unsuccessfully called by `tab_model`. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

I ran a linear mixed effects model. 
I can generate a table using

```
tab_model(BWRTmod1b,show.stat = TRUE)
```

When I change the call to get p-values based on the Kenward-Roger approximated degrees of freedom like this:

```
tab_model(BWRTmod1b,p.val= "kr" ,show.stat = TRUE)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in round(attr(pv, "df.kr", exact = TRUE)) : 
>     non-numeric argument to mathematical function

I have googled the problem and the only thing I found was a missing `pbkrtest` package, but that's not the case here. I also googled the error message itself and found that this can happen when a data frame is fed into a function that wants numerical input.  I have also updated R and reinstalled/updated all packages and that didn't help.

I don't know whether and how I can fix this and it's also entirely possible that I am missing something else. Any hints would be appreciated.

[Link to the model output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwblHGxuPB_futt0qMY47smEepC5TnKB/view?usp=sharing)

```
# working
tab_model(BWRTmod1b,show.stat = TRUE)

# not working
tab_model(BWRTmod1b,p.val= "kr" ,show.stat = TRUE) 

# long term goal
tab_model(BWRTmod1b,p.val= "kr", show.df=TRUE ,show.stat = TRUE)
```

I expected to generate a table of my linear mixed effects model results that includes degrees of freedom. I can generate a table with a summary based on Wald approximation, but I cannot get the Kenward-Roger version with degrees of freedom.

Comment: I'm afraid this is more or less unanswerable without a [mcve]. I tried constructing some basic LMMs, even forcing one to be singular by making the data set very small, and haven't managed to generate your error so far.  Do you get any warnings when fitting the model ... ?

Comment: Hi Ben, I got no error when fitting the model and I can tab it with the wald approximation. lmerTest gives me a reasonable summary, too, so I don't think there's anything wrong with the model (it converged fine and everything). Mhm. Let me see whether I can attach the model output somehow.

Comment: the link you posted needs permission ...

Comment: Oh man, sorry! I changed that. Is it working now? It should be.

Comment: Update: I refit the model after detaching lmerTest and that worked!

Comment: Hmm, I'm now puzzled trying to reproduce this/find an example where this *does* work ...

Comment: In case that helps, when I do the summary with KR df like you suggest below, it ignores the KR df argument, so that does not work, but the interface with tab_model does.

Comment: yes, but are you actually getting KR p-values? If you refit the model with `lmerTest` attached, I don't think you can get KR values ... ?  I'm pretty deeply confused at this point.  I think it might be worth posting an issue on the issues list for sjPlot ...

Comment: Oh I think you misunderstood me: I refit it WITHOUT lmerTest. So lmerTest was the issue and when I detached it, it worked.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm still not sure I get it.  In case you need it: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues

Comment: Thanks! I actually put it up there yesterday, too: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug/infelicitous interaction between the `lmerTest` and `sjPlot` packages. Reproducible example:

```
library(lmerTest)
fm3 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy,
            REML=TRUE)
sjPlot::tab_model(fm3,p.val="kr")
## Error in round(attr(pv, "df.kr", exact = TRUE)) : 
## non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

whereas the same thing works if you start with `library(lme4)` instead of `library(lmerTest)`.  It should now be [fixed in the development version of sjPlot](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/commit/052cfa4314ad59bee107f5be262ce3495151d21e)

Not sure how this interacts with `REML=TRUE` ...

Comment: Huh! Before detaching lmerTest, I tried fitting REML and that didn't work, while now I'm fitting with REML= FALSE, just without lmerTest and it works.